# Bulk generate hierarchical vocabularies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 6

I have a quite big website with restaurants. I'm saving their data (like coords, city, street, country etc.) with CCK fields.

Fields *City* and *Country* are connected with vocabularies (named *Cities* and *Countries*). What i'm trying to do is to somehow bulk save all the *Cities* terms as a child elements of a term from *Cities* taxonomy. So if i have a restaurant located in *Barcelona, Spain*, i wan't to save a *Barcelona* term (from *Cities* vocabulary) as a child element of *Spain* term (from *Countries* vocabulary).

Have you any ideas how can i make something like this ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I recently created a hierarchical taxonomy on our main premium site using some data exported from our SQLServer and used [Taxonomy CSV import/export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) to import the file. I used LibreOffice Calc to massage the data into place, then exported from LibreOffice to CSV. A [Google Docs version of my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AqOW5tWK1gZNdExycGR0NmJ5S1R4SnZiQ2hpZGllMnc&output=html)  is available, if you're interested.

Two things I remember doing:

1. I choose to import as a 'taxonomy_manager' file
2. Any term which will be used as a parent needs to appear at the top before any of its children appear.